# prove that if $S$ is a subspace of $V$,then $S ∩ S^\perp =\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Anyone can help me with this?

I have to show that the intersection between $S$ and orthogonal complement of $S$ is $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you work in an Hilbert space to talk about orthogonality.
Then, if $u\in S\cap S^{\perp}$, for any $v\in S$, we have
$$\langle u,v\rangle=0.$$
We can take $v=u$ to conclude that $\|u\|^2=0$ and then $u=0$.

Comment: The tag says "linear algebra" and the question belongs to linear algebra *only*. No need of Hilbert spaces or any other functional stuff. Of course, the proof you gave fits also in a purely linear algebra context.

Comment: You are right : I just needed the scalar product and not the completeness of Hilbert to answer the question, good point!

Answer (score 3):

Let $x\in S\cap S^\perp$.  Then $\langle x, x\rangle = 0$.

Comment: +1: This shows readily that for any subset $S$ of $V,$ we have $S\cap S^\perp\subseteq\{0\}.$ The other inclusion is straightforward for any such $S$ with $0\in S$.